# How to replace values with NA in data frame or list without changing the class in R?

Tags: r, class

I want to fill the first n objects in my list or the first n columns in my data frame with NA values without changing the class of the objects. The problem is the following:

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(1:10, nrow=2, ncol=5))
d_NA <- d
d_NA[,1] <- NA
class(d[,1]) == class(d_NA[,1]) 

l <- list(1)
l_NA <- l
l_NA[[1]] <- NA

class(l[[1]]) == class(l_NA[[1]]) # outputs to false
```

this happens because the NA that I fill into the data frame or list is of class "logical"

Now I could of course do it like this

```
d[,1] <- as.integer(NA)
l[[1]] <- as.integer(NA)
```

but I am looking for a more generic solution, that does not alter the class as long as it "has to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[NA]` (subscripted NA)

```r
class(c(TRUE, FALSE)[NA])
#> [1] "logical"
class(c(1:10)[NA])
#> [1] "integer"
class(c(0.5, 0.5)[NA])
#> [1] "numeric"
class(c("A", "b")[NA])
#> [1] "character"
class(c(Sys.time(), Sys.time())[NA])
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding this is because R is a dynamically typed language and NA itself is of type logical, your solution (of coercing NA to the desired type), as far as I know, is the best:

```
d_NA <- d
d_NA[,1] <- as.integer(NA)
class(d[,1]) == class(d_NA[,1])

l_NA <- l
l_NA[[1]] <- as.numeric(NA)

class(l[[1]]) == class(l_NA[[1]])
```

Comment: There's `NA_real_`, `NA_integer_`, `NA_character_`, and `NA_complex_` which you may use directly